# Android ListViewAdapter doesn't work properly

Tags: android, onclicklistener, listview-adapter

I'm struggling with ListViewAdapter and with OnClickListener in it.
The task is simple :

- each row in list has blue button;
- button should change color to green after the click on it;
- green color should remain on clicked button no matter how do you scroll the list.

Adapter code :

```
 public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<StuffPics> {
 Context context;
 public ArrayList<Integer> mItemsChecked;

 public ListViewAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<StuffPics> mylist) {
 super(context, resource, mylist);
 this.context = context;
 mItemsChecked = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 }

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View cell, ViewGroup parent) {
final Holder holder;
View v= cell;
if (v == null){
    holder = new Holder();
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.seepic_test, null);
    holder.mainButton1 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.main_button1);
    holder.mainButton2 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.main_button2);

    if(mItemsChecked.size()==0 || (!mItemsChecked.contains(position) && position > mItemsChecked.get(mItemsChecked.size() - 1))){
        mItemsChecked.add(position);
        } 
    v.setTag(holder);
}else{

    if(mItemsChecked.size()==0 || (!mItemsChecked.contains(position) && position > mItemsChecked.get(mItemsChecked.size() - 1))){
        mItemsChecked.add(position);
        } 
     holder = (Holder)v.getTag();

    if(!mItemsChecked.contains(position)){
            System.out.println("POSITION GREEN : " + Integer.toString(position));
            holder.mainButton1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.mainButton2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
}

holder.mainButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        mItemsChecked.remove(position);
        holder.mainButton1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.mainButton2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }  
   });
return v;
}
```

My idea is to collect all positions in mItemsChecked array, then on click of the button remove certain position from this array, then on reuse of the view dispense it according to the mItemsChecked array current status - if position is still there, then blue button, if position is not in array (button was clicked and position was removed), then green button.

Now, according to the logs it works. But not according to the actual view )

Logs :

- mItemsChecked array is collected properly;
- certain position is removing on click properly;
- System.out.println("POSITION GREEN") shows correct position, where Green button should be on scroll.

Real view :

- on click of one button two buttons are turning Green. If I click button num.2 , then scroll lower, I'll see button num.12 Green as well. If button num.4, then 14th ... if 17th, then 7th and so on through ten;
- when I scroll list back and forward other buttons are randomly turning Green as well.

And I stuck here, because Logs don't match the real view.
What am I doing wrong ? How to turn on different color on the clicked button in ListView and hold it during the list scroll ?

Answer (score 2):

your green views are getting recycled. put an else condition after your if block

```
if(!mItemsChecked.contains(position)){
        System.out.println("POSITION GREEN : " + Integer.toString(position));
        holder.mainButton1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.mainButton2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
else{
    System.out.println("POSITION Blue : " + Integer.toString(position));
        holder.mainButton1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.mainButton2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: I knew I was almost there. Thanks)

Comment: Indeed you were almost there :)